# What is the cheapest/safest way to ship a box to Japan from USA

Tags: japan, souvenirs, mail

I am not sure if this is the right group to submit this question to. I feel like this is a travel question because it involves mailing souvenirs and other things that will not fit in to a suitcase.  If this is the wrong group can you point me in the right direction please.

So we have an exchange student staying with us and she has a box to send back home to Japan. The box is huge it has all of her souvenirs and winter clothes, she wants to figure of a way so that she can send back the box without spending like a thousand dollars to ship the box back. What would be the cheapest and safest way to ship it there.

The box will be shipped from USA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mail a 50 pound (22.6 kg) package from the US to Japan [for $180 via Priority Mail International](http://ircalc.usps.gov/MailServices.aspx?country=10214&m=7&p=50&o=0&dpb=0&mdt=2015%2f05%2f08+08%3a00&r=True&l=24&h=18&w=18&g=0&dvi=50). The maximum allowed length is 60", and the maximum length plus girth combined must be less than 108".

If you [buy the postage online](https://cns.usps.com/) it is $160, and you fill out and print the customs forms at the same time. The catch is you have to get [a special customs envelope](https://store.usps.com/store/browse/productDetailSingleSku.jsp?productId=P_FORM_2976_E) that the postage label and customs forms go into; you can have these shipped to you for free or you may be able to obtain them at a local post office. If you've printed the postage and customs form online and placed them in the customs envelope, you can even have the USPS [pick up the package](https://www.usps.com/pickup/) at your home for free.

And of course the price will vary depending on the weight of the package, so you should weigh it on a reasonably accurate scale before you mail it. This service has a [weight limit](http://pe.usps.com/text/Imm/il_010.htm#ep1628203) of 66 pounds (30 kg) per package.

Comment: If you don't mind picking up the box at the airport, you can save even more by using a service like Delta Cargo. For example from Atlanta to Narita, it only costs $129 to send a 48 pound (21.8 kg) box, and it usually arrives the next day or so.

Answer (score 0):

The cheapest is likely for her to get an extra suitcase and carry it back with her. Even at the elevated prices, it'll still be cheaper than airmail.